# C++ singleton — not full C++ 11 standard

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm struggling to design a thread-safe singleton implementation in C++, but it will be targeted primarily on the Visual Studio 2012 environment.

I know that the C++ 11 standard guarantees that this

```
Foo& Instance()
{
    static Foo instance;

    return instance;
}
```

is thread-safe. But compiler used in the Visual Studio 2012 does not yet fully comply to the C++ 11 standard (at least regarding the thread-safety of static variables initialization). So I came up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

class Foo
{
    public:
        static Foo& Instance();

    private:
        Foo() { init(); }
        Foo(Foo const&);
        void operator = (Foo const&);
        void init() { std::cout << "init done." << std::endl; }
        static std::atomic<Foo*> _instance;
        static std::mutex _mutex;
};

std::atomic<Foo*> Foo::_instance = nullptr;
std::mutex Foo::_mutex;

Foo& Foo::Instance()
{
    if(_instance.load() == nullptr)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        if(_instance.load() == nullptr)
        {
            _instance = new Foo();
        }
    }

    return *_instance;
}
```

I would like to ask:

1) Is this code thread-safe?

2) Is this code OK?

Comment: That's the old singleton anti-pattern. You must lock the mutex before checking that the singleton is still null.

Comment: You're right, thank You. I guess when we would lock the mutex before the actual testing `if (_instance.load() == nullptr)` we would be safe, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Double-checked locking is not thread safe. See http://mortoray.com/2012/02/28/double-checked-locking-why-doesnt-it-work-and-how-to-fix-it/

An alternative solution than the suggest solution in the mentioned article:

```
T& thread_safe()
{
  static std::once_flag once;
  static T* result;
  struct Initialize
  {
    static void apply(T*& result) { result = new T; }
  };
  std::call_once(once, Initialize::apply(result);
  return *result;
}
```

Notes:

- If you have no std::call_one you can resort to the boost equivalent.
- Instead of using a local struct, you may use a lambda.
- As stated in the question, there is no need for this, having a C++11 conform compiler.

Comment: But isn't `std::once_flag` C++11? In which case isn't the original code safe?

Comment: @Galik Using std::once_flag to ensure thread safe initialization is different than static variable initialization (Thread safe according to C++11, but not in msvc 2013)

Answer (score 1):

At [Double-Checked Locking is Fixed In C++11](http://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/)  you can find a fine treatise on the theme, including some easy ready-made examples. Your code resembles the last one, but it's probably not OK, since you are not using the `.store()` method to copy the pointer to the new-created instance. Also it might not produce the best machine instructions.

Comment: Side Note: A nice link